# Selenium: how to select text in CSS?

Tags: python, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Could somebody please suggest how I can locate and click on "Client" using Selenium Webdriver with Python in the provided code:

```
<g class="highcharts-legend" transform="translate(647,234)">
    <g class="highcharts-legend-item" transform="translate(8,3)">
        <text x="21" style="color:#333333;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;cursor:pointer;fill:#333333;" text-anchor="start" y="15">Client</text>
        <rect x="0" y="4" width="16" height="12" fill="#4685BB">

   </g>
</g>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this `CSS` selector:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("g.highcharts-legend-item>text").click()
```

or `XPath`:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[name()='text' and text()='Client']").click()
```